# Comments module redirects to #CommentForm and doesn't show anything when submitted in processwire

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, processwire

I have been working on my website and reached the comments section. I am using processwire framework so "Comments" module comes with it. I followed every single action in order to install it. It appears nicely on my website, but whenever I enter all the needed information and click submit button it redirects me to #CommentForm section and nothing is shown but the preloader of the website. Can you give me a hand on managing Comments. Currently I am working on my localhost, thus I cannot provide a link to my website. I checked the option to send submitted comments to my email and post it if only approved by admin.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is working, apparently it didn't work because I didn't specify my email in the module setup section. I entered my email and it all started working. Do not forget to enter all the credentials